# Editing form data

Tags: php, forms

I have created a form, quite complex, with user input unique values, integers and strings etc..

The data is posted to a db, and I want an option to allow the user to return and edit their data at any time.

So let's say we have an input field, with **value="name"** and I want the user to be able to return at any time, to alter the value of that field. Which, let's say, they had previously typed in **"Dave"**.

What is the best method to re-propagate the form field, with the data they entered previously, from the db, and show that data in an input element and allow them to update the value, to say **"David"**, and then save the form.

My php coder is away for next few days, and thought I would fiddle with the code whilst I had some spare time.

Comment: I'd make sure to backup the files you may "fiddle" with. My boss usually does more bad than good when he tries to tackle the simplest of coding tasks.

Comment: lol Aaron, yer I am working on slave copy, and dummy data, he would kill me if I buggerd it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

retrieve the data based on the user, and then just echo the data into the `<input>`'s `value=""` attribute for each form element corresponding to the data.

`<input type="text" name="data-name" id="data-name" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($data-name) ?>" />`

Comment: cheers Jon, that looks exactly what I was thinking, theres also a unix stamp I can post to the page which fetches last edited date or data change isnt there too ?

Comment: that depends on how you have stored the data.  You can format a unix timestamp to a friendly "readable" format with php's `date()` function here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php ... you would just make sure to pass the unix timestamp as the second argument.